# How to plot linear term of a function expanded by Taylor seires in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I am quite new in Mathematica and I am trying to plot a linear term of a particular function in Mathematica. I have tried something like this:

```
TD = 200
Debye[x_] := 3 (x/TD)^3 NIntegrate[y^3/(Exp[y] - 1), {y, 0, TD/x}]
Fa[x_] := 8.6173324*10^(-5) x (9 *TD/(8 x) + 3 Log[1 - Exp[-TD/x]] - 
    Debye[x])
Series[Fa[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Actually I want to plot Fa[x] with the linear term expansion.
It shows some error called

> "NIntegrate::nlim: "y = 200./t is not a valid limit of integration"

However If I just simply plot Fa[x] (without the series syntax), it works. It seems I am missing something regarding the Series syntax. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: According to the documentation, you should use `Normal[]` to make the expression returned by `Series[]` work.

Comment: Can you please bit specify, I mean where to place that 'Normal[]' command? I tried it but probably I don't know where to write and then how to plot. Could you please write the explicit plot syntax including series command?

Comment: I could be wrong but I think `Series[]` needs a symbolic expression and here you have a numeric one. I think `Debye[]` has a closed analytic expression, and you can work from there

Comment: I'd recommend two changes. (1) Define `Debye` as a function that only handles explicitly numeric input. This is done as `Debye[x_?NumberQ]:=...`. (2) Make `ser` into a function also restricted to explicit numeric input (and use `Normal`, as was already noted by @egwenesedai): `ser[x_?NumberQ] := Normal[Series[Fa[y], {y, 0, 1}]] /. y -> x`. First remember to clear the prior definitions: `Clear[Debye,ser]`.

Comment: Many thanks @DanielLichtblau. I was not aware of the commands like ser and clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TD = 200;
Debye[x_] := 
 3 (x/TD)^3 Integrate[y^3/(Exp[y] - 1), {y, 0, TD/x}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
Fa[x_] := 8.6173324*10^(-5) x (9*TD/(8 x) + 3 Log[1 - Exp[-TD/x]] - Debye[x])
ser = Series[Fa[x], {x, 0, 1}] // Normal

 (* 0.00025852 x Log[1 - E^(-200/x)]*)

Plot[ser, {x, 1, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!! Many thanks @rewi. Your answer just solved what I exactly was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome!